# How do you output to video screen in dosbox?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox, vga

This code does not output anything.
How can I output the character 'A' on left corner of a new screen?

```
assume cs: code, ds: code  
code segment  
org 100h  

start:  

mov ax, 0B800h  
mov es, ax  
mov byte ptr es:[0], 'A'   

int 20h      ; exit program
code ends  
end start
```

I would like there to the letter 'A' on the left corner of an otherwise blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

> This code does not output anything.

Possibilities include:

- the video mode is not using display memory at 0xB800:0x0000 (e.g. a graphics video mode).
- the code did write 'A' but the attribute makes it invisible (e.g. black foreground with black background).
- the code did write 'A' and the attribute makes it visible; but it's overwritten or scrolled off the top of the screen as soon as the program exists (before you have a chance to see it)

To guard against all these potential problems:

- set the video mode to make sure it's using text mode
- do `mov ax,(0xF0 << 8) | 'A'` and `mov [es:0],ax` to set the attribute while also writing the character. Note: This can be optimized to a single `mov word [es:0],(0xF0 << 8) | 'A'` instruction.
- have some kind of delay before you exit (wait for time to pass, wait for user to press a key, ...).

Comment: Given that the question is in MASM (or compatible) syntax, NASM syntax doesn't work. It would be `mov word ptr [es:0],(0F0h SHL 8) OR 'A'`  . MASM doesn't use `0x` prefix and the operators aren't `<<` and `!` and `word` has to be followed by `ptr`. An example of waiting for a keystroke would be `mov ah, 0` `int 16h`